# Who is Sheshbazzar? Is he the same person as Zerubabbel?

Tags: exegesis, history, referent-identification, ezra

The Bible says:

> KJV Ezra 1:8 Even those did Cyrus king of Persia bring forth by the hand of Mithredath the treasurer, and numbered them unto Sheshbazzar, the prince of Judah.

But in the following chapters that name scarcely turns up. Instead Zerubabbel is portrayed as the prince of Judah in the place of Sheshbazzar.

Are they the same people with two names? I would like an answer from biblical and historical sources.

Comment: Do you have access to a study Bible like the New International Version?  If so, you will find detailed information regarding this question. The comments re Ezra 1:8 are most helpful. Josephus (Antiquities, 11.1.3) seems to identify Sheshbazzar with Zerubbabel. I started to type it all out but is there any point if you can read it for yourself?  Happy to copy and paste what I've done if it will help you.

Comment: Very interesting! Will go through comments from a study Bible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following came from [Lexham Bible Dictionary](https://www.logos.com/product/36564/lexham-bible-dictionary) entry on SHESHBAZZAR authored by Noah M. Marsh, proposing that the most widely accepted explanation is that Sheshbazzar and Zerubbabel were two different people.  The entry includes biblical and historical sources.

> **SHESHBAZZAR** (שֵׁשְׁבַּצַּר, *sheshebbatstsar*). First governor of Judaea appointed by Cyrus II. He returned the temple vessels and laid the temple foundations in 538 BC.
>
> **Biblical References**
>
> Sheshbazzar appears in the book of Ezra (Ezra 1:8, 11; 5:14, 16; also see 1 Esdras 2:12, 15; 6:18, 20). In Ezra 1:8, Sheshbazzar receives the temple vessels from Cyrus, which he then returns to Jerusalem with other exiles (Ezra 1:11). Williamson argues that the account of the temple vessels being returned reflects actual historical practices—evidence for this has been preserved at Persepolis (*Studies in Persian Period*, 225). The letter in Ezra 5 recounts that Cyrus appointed Sheshbazzar as governor and commanded him to return the temple vessels (Ezra 5:14). Ezra then reports that laid the foundations of the temple (Ezra 5:16).
>
> **Identity of Sheshbazzar**
> Haggai and Zechariah claim that Zerubbabel laid the foundations of the temple, not Sheshbazzar (Zech 4:9; 8:9; Hag 2:18). There are three possible solutions for the overlap between Sheshbazzar and Zerubbabel:
>
> - Sheshbazzar and Zerubbabel were actually the same person.
> - Andrew E. Steinmann suggests that Sheshbazzar was the Persian official commissioned for the project, but Zerubbabel was the actual project manager who did the work (“Chronological Note,” 520).
> - A. Gelston proposed that Sheshbazzar unsuccessfully attempted to rebuild the temple in 536 BC and Zerubbabel successfully restarted the rebuilding project in 520 BC (“Foundations of the Second Temple,” 234–35). This is the most widely accepted explanation.
>
> Based on the spellings of Sheshbazzar in the Septuagint (Sasabasar) and 1 Esdras (Sanabassar), as well as the shared title “prince of Judah,” D. J. A. Clines identifies Sheshbazzar as Shenazzar (1 Chr 3:18; *Ezra*, *Nehemiah*, *Esther*, 41). However, most modern commentators do not identify Sheshbazzar with any other biblical character (Fensham, *Ezra and Nehemiah*, 46).
>
> **Bibliography**
>
> - Clines, D.J.A. *Ezra, Nehemiah, Esther*. New Century Bible Commentary. Edited by Ronald E. Clements. Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1984.
> - Gelston, A. “The Foundations of the Second Temple.” *Vetus Testamentum* 16 (1966): 232–235
> - Fensham, F. Charles. *The Books of Ezra and Nehemiah*. New International Commentary on the Old Testament. Edited by R. K. Harrison. Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1982.
> - Japhet, S. “Sheshbazzar and Zerubbabel—Against the Background of the Historical and Religious Tendencies of Ezra—Nehemiah.” *Zietschrift für die alttestamentliche Wissenschaft*. 1982.
> - Klein, Ralph W. “Books of Ezra and Nehemiah.” Pages 661–852 in *The New Interpreter’s Bible Commentary 3*. Edited by Leander E. Keck. Nashville: Abingdon, 1999.
> - Steinmann, Andrew E. “A Chronological Note: The Return of the Exiles under Sheshbazzar and Zerubbabel (Ezra 1–2).” *Journal of the Evangelical Theological Society*. 2008.
> - Williamson, H.G. *Studies in Persian Period History and Historiography*. Forschungen zum Alten Testament 38. Tübingen: Mohr Siebeck, 2004.

The entry on ZERUBBABEL, SON OF SHEALTIEL characterizes the past attempts to identify Zerubbabel with Sheshbazzar with efforts to harmonize Ezra 3:8 and 5:16.  However, the entry (by David B. Schreiner) argues that the two people are also different:

> In response to tensions between Ezra 3:8 and 5:16, Zerubbabel has often been equated with Sheshbazzar. Ezra 3:8 credits Zerubbabel with beginning reconstruction of the temple in Jerusalem during the reign of Cyrus. However, Ezra 5:16 credits Sheshbazzar with initiating this effort. The identification of Zerubbabel with Sheshbazzar is thus a harmonization of these texts.
>
> The effort to harmonize Ezra 3:8 and 5:16 by identifying Zerubbabel with Sheshbazzar dates back to the rabbinic exegesis of the Middle Ages and has a small amount of support in certain manuscript traditions (compare discussion in Japhet, “Sheshbazzar and Zerubbabel,” 91). However, today, few scholars adhere to the position that Zerubbabel and Sheshbazzar are the same person (Albertz, *Israel in Exile*, 120–21; Meyers and Meyers, *Haggai, Zechariah* 1–8, 9–12). For example, Albertz and Japhet argue that efforts to identify Zerubbabel with Sheshbazzar are ineffective because both names are Babylonian in origin (Albertz, *Israel in Exile*, 120; Japhet, “Sheshbazzar and Zerubbabel,” 91). Japhet considers the various sources with their theological tendencies in relationship to one another and argues, “Sheshbazzar is the least of the people and the governor in the days of Cyrus, who lays the foundations of the Temple and brings the Temple vessels to Jerusalem; Zerubbabel is the leader and governor in the days of Darius, whose journey to Jerusalem brings in its wake waves of hope for redemption. Under his direction … the building is resumed and even completed” (Japhet, “Sheshbazzar and Zerubbabel,” 93).
>
> **Bibliography**
>
> - Albertz, Rainer. *Israel in Exile: The History and Literature of the Sixth Century BC*. Translated by David Green. Atlanta: Society of Biblical Literature, 2003.
> - Japhet, Sara. “Sheshbazzar and Zerubbabel—Against the Background of the Historical and Religious Tendencies of Ezra-Nehemiah.” *Zeitschrift fur die alttestamentliche Wissenschaft* 94 (1982): 66–98.

Comment: Very thorough. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Are Zerubbabel and Sheshbazzar the same people with two names?   Opinions differ.  However, the English Standard Version study Bible has this to say about Sheshbazzar:

> Sheshbazzar - one of the early leaders of the returning exiles.  The title “prince of Judah” simply means that he was a leading member of the exiled community.  In 5:14-16 the initiation of the temple’s reconstruction is attributed to Sheshbazzar, and there he is called “governor”.

Later on in the account, Sheshbazzar is identified as governor.  The ESV comments for Ezra 5:14 make this observation:

> Sheshbazzar was introduced as “the prince of Judah” in 1:8, being the one who had received directly from King Cyrus the charge to rebuild the temple.  Here he is called “governor”, a name applied to Tattenai himself in 5:3; it seems that the term could be used somewhat loosely, since Judah would not have had a “governor” on a par with the governor of the entire province Beyond the River (v. 6, etc.). Darius’s reply also refers to a “governor” of the Jews” (6:7), a name given to Zerubbabel in Hag. 1:1.

And who was Tattenai?  He was the governor of the province Beyond the River – the name of the Persian province, which apparently included Jerusalem, until the decree of Cyrus returned the land to the Jews.

Are Zerubbabel and Sheshbazzar the same people with different names and titles?  The evidence is inconclusive and the jury is probably still out.

I mention this merely as additional information to the excellent answer already provided by Grateful Disciple.

Comment: @AndrewShanks - Appreciate the edit.  Well spotted!

Answer (score 0):

Were Zerubabbel and Sheshbazzar the same person?

For starters, it would be quite odd that the writer(s) of Ezra would infer that they were 2 separate and distinct persons if they were the same person. It is very clear from reading the book of Ezra that they are 2 separate persons.

In Ezra chapter 5, the Jews resume construction on the temple structure in 520 BC (second year of Darius); Ezra 4:24. This was after the foundation had been laid some 16-18 years prior (just a couple of years after their return from the Babylonian exile; Ezra 3:2-10.

They were then encouraged by the prophets          Haggai; Haggai ch. 1- and  Zechariah.

Ezra 5:1-2 NASB

> 1When the prophets, Haggai the prophet and Zechariah the son of Iddo, prophesied to the Jews who were in Judah and Jerusalem in the name of the God of Israel, who was over them, 2then Zerubbabel the son of Shealtiel and Jeshua the son of Jozadak rose up and began to rebuild the house of God which is in Jerusalem; and the prophets of God were with them, supporting them.<

After the Jews began building the temple     structure, on the foundation that had     already been laid; Ezra 3:10, an attempt to     hinder their work was led by Tattenai the     governor beyond the Euphrates. The leaders     of the Jews Zerubabbel, Joshua and other     elders were approached by Tattenai.

Ezra 5:3 Nasb

> At that time Tattenai, the governor of the province beyond the Euphrates River, and Shethar-bozenai and their colleagues came to them and spoke to them as follows: “Who issued you a decree to rebuild this [a]temple and to finish this structure?”<

At this point Zerubabbel, Joshua and the     elders responded to Tattenai and colleagues     by providing information on what was going     on with the construction. In Order that     they may relay the information to king     Darius (the Persian).

Ezra 5:4-5 NASB

> 4Then we told them accordingly what the names of the men were who were reconstructing this building. 5But the eye of their God was on the elders of the Jews, and they did not stop them until the report could reach Darius, and then the decree concerning it could be sent back.<

Based on the information that Zerubbabel,     Joshua and the elders provided, and the     eyewitness account, a letter was written by     Tattenai and associates, then delivered to     Darius.

Ezra 5:6-9 NASB

> 6This is the copy of the letter that Tattenai, the governor of the province beyond the Euphrates River, and Shethar-bozenai and his colleagues the officials, who were beyond the River, sent to Darius the king. 7They sent the report to him in which it was written as follows: “To Darius the king, all peace. 8May it be known to the king that we have gone to the province of Judah, to the house of the great God which is being built with large stones, and [b]beams are being laid in the walls; and this work is being performed with great care and is succeeding in their hands.<

Above you see the eyewitness account of     what Tattenai is expressing to King Darius.     While below, we see the source of the other      information given in the letter. It is the     account of Zerubbabel, Joshua and the     elders,explaining to Darius the     circumstances of the past.

Ezra 5:9-10NASB

> 9Then we asked those elders and said to them as follows: ‘Who issued you a decree to rebuild this temple and to finish this structure?’ 10We also asked them their names so as to inform you, in order that we might write down the names of the men who were [c]in charge. 11So they [d]answered us as follows, saying,<

Above we see clearly that the answer of     Zerubbabel and the other elders is given     below. Zerubbabel gives the information to     Tattenai, who in turn relays the     information to Darius.

Below is the information provided by     Zerubbabel and the other elders of the Jews     who had returned from exile.

Ezra 5:11-16 NASB

> 11So they [d]answered us as follows, saying,
> saying, ‘We are the servants of the God of heaven and earth, and are rebuilding the temple that was built many years ago, which a great king of Israel built and finished. 12But because our fathers provoked the God of heaven to wrath, He handed them over to Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon, the Chaldean, who destroyed this temple and deported the people to Babylon. 13However, in the first year of Cyrus king of Babylon, King Cyrus issued a decree to rebuild this house of God. 14Also the gold and silver utensils of the house of God which Nebuchadnezzar had taken from the temple in Jerusalem and brought them to the temple of Babylon, King Cyrus took them from the temple of Babylon and they were given to one whose name was Sheshbazzar, whom he had appointed governor. 15And he said to him, “Take these utensils, go and deposit them in the temple in Jerusalem, and have the house of God rebuilt in its place.” 16Then that Sheshbazzar came and laid the foundations of the house of God in Jerusalem; and from then until now it has been under construction and it is not yet completed.’<

If you notice above, based on the     information that Zerubbabel and the elders     provided, there was another man named     Sheshbazzar who came and laid the     foundations of the second temple. This man     was appointed by king Cyrus a greatly     revered king in Persian history and the     “father in law” of King Darius. If     Zerubbabel were Sheshbazzar, surely he     would have informed Darius. Furthermore,     the danger of lying to a king could be very     dangerous. Below is the last verse of Ezra     5.

Ezra 5:17 NASB

> 17And now, if it pleases the king, let a search be conducted in the king’s treasure house, which is there in Babylon, as to whether a decree was issued by King Cyrus to rebuild this house of God in Jerusalem; and let the king send to us his decision concerning this matter.”<

After this a search was made in the palace     in Ectabana and the decree of Cyrus was     found; Ezra 6:1-6

After this, King Darius reinforced that     decree and made a few addendums, if you     will. Providing monetary assistance and     even going so far as to threaten Tattenai     and associates with execution if they     attempt to hinder the Jews. He doesn’t     sound like a king I would want to lie to     :).

Ezra 6:6-11 NASB

> 6“Now as for you, Tattenai, governor of the province beyond the Euphrates River, Shethar-bozenai, and [i]your colleagues, the officials of the provinces beyond the River, [j]stay away from there. 7Leave that work on the house of God alone; let the governor of the Jews and the elders of the Jews rebuild that house of God on its site. 8Furthermore, I issue a decree concerning what you are to do for these elders of Judah in the rebuilding of that house of God: the full cost is to be paid to those people from the royal treasury out of the taxes of the provinces beyond the Euphrates River, and that without interruption. 9And whatever is needed, bulls, rams, and lambs for burnt offerings to the God of heaven, and wheat, salt, wine, and anointing oil, as the priests in Jerusalem order, it is to be given to them daily without fail, 10so that they may offer acceptable sacrifices to the God of heaven and pray for the lives of the king and his sons. 11And I issued a decree that any person who violates this decree, a timber shall be pulled out of his house and he shall be impaled on it; and his house shall be turned into a refuse heap on account of this.<

So were Sheshbazzar and Zerubabbel the same person? Well,according to the information provided by Zerubabbel and the other elders, they were different people. There is likely enough evidence in the book of Ezra alone to come to a safe conclusion that they were not the same person